# Are only Force Sensitives able to see Force Ghosts?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

And is the clarity of the Force Ghost as visible to you directly proportional to how much training in using/sensing the Force you have?

In the Original Trilogy, Obi-Wan's ghost only appears to Luke; even when informing someone on Hoth Base of Luke's injury would have been very helpful. Additionally, Obi-Wan is able to appear more 'clearly' to Luke as he progresses in his training.

As such, this made me wonder if one needs to be a trained force sensitive in order to have contact with force spirits? Is there any information on these lines from canon?

Alternatively, is there any canon incidence of Force Ghosts appearing to people who are not trained force sensitives?

Comment: Leis doesn't see the force ghosts at the ends of ROTJ

Comment: In the Lego Star Wars games, force ghosts are invisible to non-force users

Comment: @Richard - can you get any less canon than Lego Starwars games? (first person to mention Christmas Special gets forced to watch it. With eyes forced open)

Comment: @Richard Thanks for pointing both those out - Lego games are certainly non-canon, but it worth a mention, i think.

Comment: @DVK - Lego games are at least licensed. Plus, Disney has just decanonised the entire EU

Comment: @Richard - Leia wasn't a trained force sensitive at the end of RotJ, which is perhaps why she didn't see the force ghosts.

Comment: @DavidCox - I agree. It would certainly suggest that force ghosts are only fully visible to trained adepts.

Comment: @Richard I'll be happy to accept your points as an answer - you seem to have covered the revelant info about this, out there :)

Comment: @Shisa - I thought my answer was nicely comprehensive. Is there anything you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum, according to the ghastly James Kahn novel Luke apparently did not see proper force ghosts at the end of ROTJ either - rather he saw "ephemeral faces that spoke only to the shadows of the flames" (and he had interacted with Ben's "Ghost" on Dagobah a few chapters before that, so he would know the difference).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There appear to be three major components required for someone to be able to see a Force Ghost; **inherent Force ability, mental state and specific (advance) training to seeing Force Ghosts**

- Luke hears what can be best described as an "echo" of [Ben Kenobi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WBG2rJZGW8&feature=youtu.be&t=11m49s) after just a one or two Jedi lessons, however he doesn't appear to be able to *converse* with him, nor can he *see* him.
- After Luke has spent some time on his own practicing his Force powers, and at a time when he was mentally receptive (near death, recently having used the Force) [he was able to *see* Ben](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsY71TFWSSs&feature=youtu.be&t=2m27s), but was not able to converse with him.
- Ben appears to Luke in The Empire Strikes Back. In the new canon novelisation, he explicitly states that Luke can see him now because his training is sufficiently advanced

> Suddenly, another voice answers you. Rich and kind and understanding.
>   Ben’s voice. “You don’t know that, Luke.”
>   You turn, and see him. He is standing beside Yoda. He shimmers.
>   “Ben!” you cry. “Are you…Aren’t you…?”
>   Obi-Wan Kenobi smiles. **“I am still a part of the Force. You have, through your training, learned to see me.”**
>   You stare, drinking in the sight of your first master, your friend.
>
> <sub>[The Empire Strikes Back: So You Want to Be a Jedi?](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F)</sub>

- Luke can clearly see the [three Force Ghosts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EN4tcT1PRU) at the end of Return of the Jedi, however Leia (who hasn't had any Jedi training) cannot.
- Yoda tells Obi-Wan (at [the end of Revenge of the Sith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_VKYf89XEE&feature=youtu.be&t=3m35s)) that specific training is required for him to communicate effectively with Qui-Gon

> **YODA:** *Master Kenobi, wait a moment. In your solitude on Tatooine, training I have for you.*
>
> **OBI-WAN:** Training??
>
> **YODA:** *An old friend has learned the path to immortality. One who has returned from the netherworld of the Force. Your old Master*
>
> **OBI-WAN:** *Qui-Gon?!*
>
> **YODA:** ***How to commune with him. I will teach you.***

Comment: That latter bit seems like it contradicts the fact that Luke is able to 'commune' with Ben without any specific force ghost seance training at all.  (not the first time the prequels have done that)

Comment: @Paul -  Meditation and being in the right frame of mind seem to help. Presumably as Yoda and Ben practiced at it, they got better at both seeing and (crucially) being seen

Answer (score 6):

Yoda said in Episode III that he can teach Obi Wan to talk to Qui Gon Jinn. So at least it is not trivial to converse with Force Ghosts.

But Luke made it without any training on Dagobah.
Also Leia cant see the Yoda, Obi Wan and Vader on Endor.

Therefore there is no consensus in the Movies about the Force Ghosts. Who ever wrote the script for the conversation in Episode III must have got the order to make an explanation about the force ghosts in the old trilogy.

I don’t know what the Expended Universe tells about them. Maybe the Disney/Lucasfilm *Star Wars* films will explain a bit more about them.

Comment: As lovely as conversate is as a word, I think you mean converse!

Comment: yeah the dark side of the language is strong in me... thanks for pointing out.

Comment: can i know why the -1 ?

Comment: @Fulli it wasn't me, but _"I don't know what the Expended Universe tells about them"_ might easily trigger a downvote. In such a universe, if the movies offer no explaination, you are _expected_ to search in the expanded universe. IMHO it is acceptable to just care about the movie version of something only in case the movie _does_ have an explaination, not if it _doesn't_.

Answer (score -2):

Force ghosts could chose who saw them as well as you had to either be training to be a Jedi or be one so that is why others, like Han and Leia, couldn't see them.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence for this assertion?